# Linking several entities within an API

Tags: api-design, symfony4, api-platform.com

***Edit (2018/02/18):*** *Since I'm freshly subscribed on SO, if my question is unclear, or if there is a problem with formatting, please let me know.*

I have a problem while creating a REST API with Symfony4 and API-Platform.

### Things that work :

There are three entities in my Symfony project :

- Recipe (with cooking time, steps, etc)
- Ingredient (with description, photo, etc)
- LinkIR (which contains a link to a Recipe, one to an Ingredient, and a quantity needed for said Ingredient in said Recipe)

When creating my API with API-Platform, I manage to create basic CRUD operations for every Entity.

### Here begins my problem :

When I land on my "Pasta" page (Ingredient), I'd like to display every Recipe using Pasta (and the quantity you need for this Recipe). I could do it by calling :

- One my Ingredient method to get my Pasta data
- N times LinkIR method to get a list of Recipe.id (and quantities)
- N times Recipe method to get all the Recipe data

This could work, but it would be slow, not reliable and it will overload my API server quickly.

Is there any way to display my whole page (1 Ingredient + N Links + N Recipes) while calling my API only once ? I began searching in the direction of API-Platform's Subresources, but without result so far.

Comment: You will have the same question when you will try to create one recipe with N ingredients with only one call (and not N call for ingredients to create them and then on call for the recipe with all iris of ingredients). For instance i didn't find any good information about how to do this.

Comment: Maybe you can try "Creating Custom Operations and Controllers" which will allow you to create Action that will add new route for your entity. In the Resposne you will return an array with 3 keys: ingredients, LinkIO and recipe for example. But not sure that it's the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Group annotation for the collection member you want to include. For example if Ingredient has a Doctrine relation to Recipe you can tag that relation with a Group name. Please notice that you need to add the annotation to all the members you want to be visible in you response.

```
/**
 * @Group("read")
 */
private $recipes;
```

Additionally you need to tell the serialization process to utilize that group.

```
/*
 * @ApiResource(attributes={
 *     "normalization_context"={"groups"={"read"}}
 * })
 */
class Ingredient {
```

You should be able to do the same from "other direction".
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization

Also think about the right level of doing it in one request. Fetching larger doctrine collections and hydrating them will end up slow. A good solution might be to get all the Recipes for a certain ingredient in one request. That's just a normal collection get with a filter which says "all recipes for ingedient x".
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters